# How do I implement text formatting with rules?

Tags: javascript, string, function, formatting

Let me start with what we already know. JS Engine finds ${ ... } in `` and executes the expression inside, then puts whatever that returns as a string. Okay, this is build-in functionality:

```js
const name = "Dick Smith";

const str = `Hello, ${name}`; 

console.log(str); // Hello, Dick Smith
```

Now, in this case I will use "" and let's say I want to find every () and do the same thing, how can I implement that ? How should that `magicFunction()` look like?
EXP:

```
const name "Dick Smith";

const str = magicFunction("Hello, (name)");

console.log(str); // Hello, Dick Smith
```

---

**Details:**

That magic function gets a string as a parameter and returns another string.

```js
function magicFunction(str){
  // Does some magic
  return str;
}
```

**Help**

You can use `eval()` to execute the expression, if you want.

---

**NOTE:** inside of () can be everything, even function expressions like `() => {}` or `() => ("Hello")` or even `(function foo(){...})()`. Anyway, it can  be everything that the JS engine can understand and execute.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic idea covering only the scenario mentioned in the question. You need to expand it to your exact requirement by improving the regex.

```js
const magicFunction = (input) => {
  const regex = /(?:\([^\(\)]*\))/g;
  const matches = input.match(regex);

  matches.map(match => {
    console.log(`Match: ${match}`);
    console.log(`Expression: ${eval(match)}`);

    input = input.replace(match, eval(match));
  });

  document.write(input);
}

const name = "Dheemanth Bhat";
const skill = () => "JavaScript";
const age = 27;
const rep = 1749 + 25;
const str = magicFunction("name: (name), age: (age) skill: (skill) rep: (rep).");
```

**NOTE**: Explanation for the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/frfxi2/1).